# Use Windows Workflow Foundation to develop timesheet approval and submit system

Tags: windows, workflow-foundation

I'm planning to develop a timesheet system that requires users to fill out a form, submit, and requires manager approve/reject, and finally submit to finance. Since there's quite a bit of workflow, is WF a good tool for this kind of thing? I'm going to code it in ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workflow would be a good fit for all process related code you need to write. So stuff like the submission, approval or rejection and handling the fact the it is dormant for an excessive amount of time.

A few things to keep in mind.

- If you are going to use ASP.NET I presume the workflow will be hosted there. So you need to make sure the workflows can run after IIS recycles the AppDomain.
- Think about whether to use WF4 or WF3. WF4 is a complete new animal and only in beta. WF3 was release as part of the .NET 3.0 release but has a limited future. It is sill there in .NET 4 and will still be supported bu the bulk of the work will be on WF4.

Comment: I can use WF4. Why IIS AppDomain matters with the workflow? Thank you.

Comment: IIS will recycle the AppDomain when it sees fit to do so and when there are no more external request being handled. But your workflow might still be running as the result of a request and will be killed. Provided you use persistence it can restart in another thread but the new AppDomain will have to spin up before that can be done. And depening on the version of IIS and setting that normally means then the next external request comes in.